# Как округлять большие числа, к примеру 33250 в 35000 (с шагом в 5 тысяч)

Tags: javascript

Какой функцией я смогу округлять большие числа с шагом в 5 тысяч?

Пример:

```
3100 -> 5000
7912 -> 10000
13520 -> 15000
```

и так далее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так?

```js
console.log(floor(3500, 5000))
console.log(floor(7912, 5000))
console.log(floor(13250, 5000))


function floor(i, d) {
    return Math.round(i/d)*d;
}
```